# Auto-rotate in android sdk doesn't work

Tags: java, android, sdk, orientation, screen-orientation

On my app, when I first press ctrl+F12 the screen changes to Landscape from Portrait. However, when I press ctrl+F12 or ctrl+F11 again, the screen does not revert back to Portrait, but the actual emulator changes orientation. How do I fix this?

Comment: I use "7" on the numpad with numLock turned off.. and it works good for me..

Comment: Screen orientation seems to be buggy in the last emulator version.